# mysql insert sub query not working

Tags: php, mysql

Please see my query,

```
insert into wp_9m8phu_term_relationships as rel
    (object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order)
values
    (
     'select object_id+1 as object_id from wp_9m8phu_term_relationships 
      where object_id!='' order by object_id desc limit 0,1',
     '".$fnds_id."',
     0
)
```

This is query not working. Anybody help me on this regards.

Comment: where are you calling it from, php? what is not working, is there an error message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the single quotes ('). Your query should look like this:

```
insert into wp_9m8phu_term_relationships as rel (object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order)
values('select object_id+1 as object_id from wp_9m8phu_term_relationships 
        where object_id!=\'\' order by object_id desc limit 0,1','".$fnds_id."',0
)
```

And if you're calling that SQL statement from PHP (as the second value suggests), you should make sure that you escape quotes contained in the variable `$fnds_id` as well (if using mysqli for accesing the database, you should e.g. use [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is syntax erro
try this

```
insert into wp_9m8phu_term_relationships as rel (object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order)
values("select object_id+1 as object_id from wp_9m8phu_term_relationships 
        where object_id<>'' order by object_id desc limit 0,1",'".$fnds_id."',0)
```